# Socket.IO infinite loop on connection

Tags: websocket, io, socket.io

Socket.IO make an infinte loop on connection !
It's weird and never happen until now. I don't know what's wrong. I try to rebuild the package, I copy some code from an older source and the same result...

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected << infinite loop');
});
```

It's a basic ExpressJS server with http on top.

```
const
port        = process.env.PORT || 3200,
app         = require('express')(),
express     = require('express'),
mysql       = require('mysql'),
bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
path        = require('path'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
http        = require('http').Server(app),
io          = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Client-Side

```
var socket = io();
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code ?

Comment: Yes, sure. I will edit the post

Comment: It also make alot of request. Request URL:http://localhost:3200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1499200444120-546

Comment: And the code of the client?

Comment: Isn't a development issue. I think it's something wrong with the package !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show continuous connection message in nodejs socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698594/show-continuous-connection-message-in-nodejs-socket-io)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem was at the client-side, I don't load the latest version of socket.io like on the server-side. In my package.json I have 2.0.3 and at the client-side was 1.2.0.. For everyone who have this problem

Comment: Thank you. I ran into the same problem. Does anyone know how to refuse connections if the client doesn't have the proper socket io version (or any other fix for that matter)?

Comment: For the record it's actually the same library for client and server. They have a version up on Cloudflare, the current one is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js

Comment: basically 2 hours troubleshooting down the drain. Either I missed some important debug / stack trace configs, or this is just poorly implemented error logging on socket.ios end

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I emitted an array (on connection) and not an object...

I solved it by wrapping the array with {} so I'm now sending an object... i.e {array}...

e.g:

```
myArray = [{blah:"some value"},{blah2:"some other value"}];

socket.emit('target',myArray); //results in infinite loop

socket.emit('target',{myArray}); //sends ok and not looping
```

No need for socket version to match on server and client... in my case the client is c# and my server is node.js