# Why does nodejs server with socket.io causing endless loop on connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, socket.io

We are a little group of 2 developers trying to implement a Simple Chat Server with node js and socket.io. We are using github. When I pulled my partners changes and does npm start, I found my console outputing "a user is connected" in an **endless loop**.

Here is the code (the part that is meant to output a user connected once: `socket.on('user login', function(newuser)`...) .
**index.js**:

```
//dependencies
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app); //http server
//initialize a new instance of socket.io by passing http server
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var users = []; //List of online users
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user: '+socket.username + ' logged out.');
    var date = new Date();
    io.emit('info message', {timestamp: date.toUTCString(), user: socket.username + ' logged out.'});
    //TO DO: Delete user from list.
  });

...
```

**index.html** script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-2.1.1.js"></script>


<script>

$(function () {
          var socket = io();

          /*
          * On submit of form with id 'entername' client sends entered username to server.
          * After sending div-Container loginDiv will be hidden and messageDiv will be shown.
          * And last: set value of usernameinput to ''.
          * */
          $('#enterName').submit(function () {
             //console.log($('#userNameInput').val());
             socket.emit('user login',$('#userNameInput').val());
             $('#loginDiv').hide();
             $('#messageDiv').show();
             $('#userNameInput').val('');
             return false;
          });
});
</script>
```

**package.json** dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: Is the github and pull part relevant to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Check the code that is performing the `socket.emit('user login')` on the client side. There’s nothing in the code provided that would cause the `'user login'` event handler to be invoked endlessly. Same thing for opening a connection, you must be connecting this socket server repeatedly.

Comment: @t.niese no, but I mentioned it because there could be a problem with the modules when pushing to the repo

Comment: @peteb I added the code from my index.html and package.json files. As you can see, there are the same socket.io versions ( I read that this can cause the infinite loop )

Comment: I would try wrapping your client side code with `socket.on('connect', () => {})` so it only registers the form handler after a successful connection was made. I personally have never heard of or encountered an issue where the socket versions differing caused this issue.

Comment: @peteb  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913564/socket-io-infinite-loop-on-connection

Comment: Thats a difference between Socket.io v1 & v2, that would make sense since there are probably large changes from v1=>v2, hence the major version change. However, you don't show that here. Also, you keep changing what you're providing as code. You had a Socket.io v1.7 dependency showing before. Did you try my suggestion with the `socket.on('connect', () => {})` handler?

Comment: Yes I changed the code because I tried the newest v2.1. Thanks for the help, I solved the problem and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, I had to use the same socket.io version on client-side & server-side. Therefore, I installed socket.io again (server-side), took the version (found that in package.json under dependencies) and searched here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io/ for the script src to bind into my html so it will be loaded on client-side.
updated index.html scriptsource in my case :

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Before, I just changed the version numbers into the src without searching the right url.